# When I add min pool size configuration in a connection string I get an exception

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I need to set min pool size in my connection string. But it gives me this exception:

> TestProject.TestW2E.GetUserByIdTest:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail] : An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

```
<add name="DbModel" connectionString="password=apassword;user id=auser;persistsecurityinfo=True;server=w2itest.cloudapp.net;database=db;Max Pool Size=45; Min Pool Size=10;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

I can't figure out why it sees the connection string as invalid. I tried setting pooling to true. I also tried specifying min pool size only.

When I try to read the `innerexception` there is none.

After the exception I can't log in to my mysql db, I get an error: "too many connections".

Comment: Maybe you have a MySQL Connector/Net version earlier than 6.7? The `MaximumPoolSize` and `MinimumPoolSize` connection string options weren't supported before that. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)

Comment: That is correct , but I'm using the 6.9.5 connector